# Checkboxes are being checked before click handler is even called

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events, preventdefault

I have the following snippets: http://jsfiddle.net/L7rne/5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/L7rne/6/

It turns out that if you pause execution of the script in the click event handler, then the checkbox is checked, even though there is `event.preventDefault()`.

I tried this in Firefox 7 and Chrome 15 and both behave in the same way.

I'm almost sure that it's a correct behaviour but somehow I cannot find any reference why it's like that.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

#### EDIT:

When you start with checked checkboxes then it becomes even more interesting:
http://jsfiddle.net/L7rne/8/ - the checkbox becomes unchecked but its value stays **checked**
http://jsfiddle.net/L7rne/9/ - the checkbox becomes unchecked but its value becomes **false**

(This is consistent with pure Javascript code using `checkbox.checked` and `checkbox.getAttribute('checked')`, so I'm not pasting another jsfiddle snippets)

#### EDIT2:

COBOLdinosaur in one of the comments [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113076/checkboxes-are-being-checked-before-click-handler-is-even-called/8113141#8113141) me to this: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation, but IMHO that only confirms my point of view...

Comment: I think what's being misunderstood here is that when the event takes place, it needs to traverse *down* the DOM (capture phase) to find the target. The target is then notified (target phase), then the event bubbles *up* the DOM tree (bubble phase). There's plenty of time in between for the browser to act upon the event. An event should not hold a browser hostage. The behavior you expect would be synchronous (blocking), and harmful to the user.

Comment: @Matt McDonald: Ok, that might explain it, but even if it is so then `preventDefault()` name sounds misleading and I'd love to see a piece of documentation for it explicitely saying that it works in the bubble phase and stating the implications that fact causes.

Comment: Furthermore, an event handler can be alerted at *any* phase of the event cycle. If a handler is bound to the target (node that dispatched/created the event), it will be notified at the target phase. If a handler is attached to an ancestor of the node (and if the event can and does bubble), that handler will be notified either at the bubble phase or capture phase, depending on the options set on the handler. `preventDefault` will "prevent"/repeal the default action (if applicable) of the event. Remember, the handler *needs* to be called.

Comment: If `stopPropagation` is used, the event is effectively halted at its current position in the DOM tree. This means it cannot traverse down (if in the capture phase), or up (if in the target or bubbling phase). More here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow

Comment: @Matt: What you write makes sense but I don't see how it applies to my question.. Take a look at [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation) - it clearly says that "listeners then have the option of canceling the implementation's default action or allowing the default action to proceed" - and here we have a case in which the default action is already done, and we can only revert it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I'm understanding the problem. why wouldn't it be the right behaviour?

seriously, let's say you write some code that shows/hides a div based on whether a checkbox is ticked or not.

so, you write an onclick. if the checkbox is unticked, and then you click it, what do you think should be done to the div? obviously, you would expect the event to find the checkbox to be checked.

Comment: Ok, so the event finds the checkbox to be checked, shows the div and then we have a visible div and non-checked checkbox? Even if this is correct for some reason, take a look at my snippets 8 and 9 - if you have a visible div and checked checkbox, then after unchecking the checkbox it is rendered as non-checked, its `.checked`/`.is(':checked')` property becomes `false` as expected, but it still has "checked" attribute set. And this is weird.

Answer (score 0):

By time the event handler fires, the event has already taken place, and the browser is re-rendering in response.  If the handler gets suspended, then the browser completes the work because nothing prevented it.

Its like calling the police to a bank robbery, and they are in a traffic accident on the way. The robbers get away.  The deed is done.

Comment: When I click the checkbox then I expect click event handler to be fired and then the default action to take place - same as for e.g. clicking a link. If the reverse would happen (i.e. default action first, click handlers next), then intercepting link clicks wouldn't be possible. Also, `preventDefault()` should *prevent* the default action, not revert it. I'm perfectly happy to be proved wrong, but I need something more concrete (e.g. link to some chapter in DOM specification, explaining these issues in details).

Comment: So does suspending the function result in the event continuing? It appears so.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've found there [sec. 1.2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation) which basically says that we the problem shouldn't exist, at least IMHO.. :)

Comment: I don't know that I agree with your opinion, but I can understand why you hold it.  When you conduct a repeatable experiment, and consistently see the same behavior, then it is valid to assume that is the expected behavior even if the documentation does not appear to support what is observed. It may be a bug or perhaps a weakness in documentation. An argument can be made to support either.  This was interesting to explore.